# Complete Yum Restore of CentOS 7 Repos

Tags: centos7, yum, repository

I have googled and tried all the solutions I can find to this.  An admin somehow broke yum trying to install an mssql package by adding the repo, then tried different way to fix, as did I.
I deleted all repos and need to start over.  Different Stack solutions have suggested trying

> ```
> rpm -Uvh --force http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-7.3.10.1160.88.1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
> rpm -Uvh --force http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-7.3.10.1160.88.1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
> rpm -iv --replacepkgs http://vault.centos.org/7.3.10/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-release-7.3.10.1160.88.1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
> ```

I also copied and pasted yum.repos.d from another CentOS 7, but not exactly same version.  It was 3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64 and this one is 3.10.0-1160.88.1

None of this has worked and I am at my wits end.  From what I have gleaned so far, I need an rpm named centos-release-7.3.10.1160.88.1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm to replace the repos correctly but cannot find one.

Can anyone help?

Comment: In StackOverflow you get the answer. What else do you expect? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76839492/2908599

Comment: restore from backup. that's the easiest way imho

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on https://stackoverflow.com/a/76839492/2908599 but that was closed  before I saw [Mikael Öhman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370594/mikael-%C3%96hman) answer.  StackOverflow was wrong board.